# Prevent modal from closing if value contains dot

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have modal with input

```js
 function check(){
    if($("#columnName").val().indexOf(".") != -1){
    alert("Column name cann't contain commas!");
    return false;
    }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="columnName" class="form-control">
and button

    <input type="button" id="applyButton" value="Apply" class="btn btn-default" onclick="check();">
```

But even though I return false if the value contains dot, the popup still closes. I want it to stay opened until user deletes dots

Comment: your alert works?

Comment: Yes, alert appears

Comment: you should write `onclick="return check()"` instead of `onclick="check()"`

Comment: Thanks. But even with onclick="return check()" it still closes

Comment: because of your implementation of `check()` which never returns true. Look at my answer

Comment: I took your realization and result is the same. I have no idea what can be wrong really. Also I've replaced != to !==

Answer (score 1):

your function never returns `true`, so your `check()` will always fail.

```
function check(){
  if($("#columnName").val().indexOf(".") != -1){
    alert("Column name cann't contain commas!");
    return false;
  }
  return true
}
```

some examples powered by me and @charlietfl

https://jsfiddle.net/xe7uwr87/1/

greetings

Comment: Doesn't make a difference if don't return what function returns

Comment: i don't get what you are saying here, what is wrong?

Comment: ah now i get what you are saying, thanks for the fiddle - i only wanted to demonstrate why the function always was true and therefor never checked anything. Updated your fiddle with more exaples - https://jsfiddle.net/xe7uwr87/1/

Comment: Don't think you got the point or see what value of the additional examples is

Comment: so explain it to me :D i will delete the post if it is wrong

Comment: The return in the function is useless by itself (and does nothing) without the inline return

Comment: that's why i added `<a href="#" onclick="alert(test())">test 3</a>` example. It depends on what i want to do with the return value. Do you think this answer should be deleted?

Comment: What is that supposed to show? Has no relevance to OP's issue. You still seem to not be getting the point of the inline return

Answer (score 0):

Use this example

```
 $('#ModalId').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
      if($("#columnName").val().indexOf(".") != -1){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        return false;
      }
        return true;
    });
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

```
function check(){
   if($("#columnName").val().indexOf(".") != -1){
    alert("Column name cann't contain commas!");
    return false;
   }else {
       $('.modal').modal('hide');
   }
}
```

Comment: i am pretty sure that this will also work, but due to the method's name is `check()` i'd recommend to do nothing else but checking here - thus you should either return `true` or `false`. The `.modal('hide')` function call is not perfectly placed here imo

Comment: you can add code before modal hide if check is true

Comment: just like i said, this will work - but i would have implemented it in another way :)

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways.

Firstly, to utilize your own example: you should be writing `onclick="return check()"` instead of `onclick="check()"` and method should `return true` in the else part.

Another thing you can do is to listen to `'hide.bs.modal'` event and then add this code and then prevent the modal from closing by stopping the event propagation and bubbling as answered by @jalay-oza